# Parsing out reCaptcha challenge key

Tags: c#, regex, json

so I've been trying something for someone that requires the captcha to solved but webbrowser is too slow to grab it so I'm doing it with webrequests. Problem is that I need to grab the challenge key and I've had no luck with it. It looks like...

```
var RecaptchaState = {
    challenge : '03AHJ_VuuOA-onKBOBYPP4ZWNEM4amq2l-ocAKYyDHYNFYedo7JsuX5xRR0WH-x5Wh8_n2O-iAybFyloxaxUwzMIzVgXBfjTdJ0CP5LKp1QWaGV4L7iTZAQ_xBWmKU_xTZquGaYMzMm8javZHQZG4nVeVKAuhJSvkmm9v2A0YV1Dkq_4yNywEc73kYpzZFLkZxduca3WLsAg7SZCA46VZadR_6JqILT6QnkTVfUXi0O6Qe3-C653oNrErJKPihVmx1apU96qNboXlo4LzDA3ACuO763QM_qUUCpg',
    timeout : 1800,
    lang : 'en',
    server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
```

So after challenge  : it needs to grab the key in ' ' along with it. I thought I could use something like JSON.Net to parse it, it won't take it though since it's really *not* pure JSON. I was thinking maybe Regex? I'm awful with Regex though so I wouldn't even know how to do it. Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot parse it with Json.Net, you will have to at least have access to it as a string, and then you can obtain the value you need using the regex (assuming you need a value after `challenge:`):

```
(?<=challenge\s*:\s*')[^']+(?=')
```

Code:

```
var bad_json = "challenge : '03AHJ_VuuOA-onKBOBYPP4ZWNEM4amq2l-ocAKYyDHYNFYedo7JsuX5xRR0WH-x5Wh8_n2O-iAybFyloxaxUwzMIzVgXBfjTdJ0CP5LKp1QWaGV4L7iTZAQ_xBWmKU_xTZquGaYMzMm8javZHQZG4nVeVKAuhJSvkmm9v2A0YV1Dkq_4yNywEc73kYpzZFLkZxduca3WLsAg7SZCA46VZadR_6JqILT6QnkTVfUXi0O6Qe3-C653oNrErJKPihVmx1apU96qNboXlo4LzDA3ACuO763QM_qUUCpg'";
var challenge_value = Regex.Match(bad_json, @"(?<=challenge\s*:\s*')[^']+(?=')").Value;
```

Output:

```
03AHJ_VuuOA-onKBOBYPP4ZWNEM4amq2l-ocAKYyDHYNFYedo7JsuX5xRR0WH-x5Wh8_n2O-iAybFyloxaxUwzMIzVgXBfjTdJ0CP5LKp1QWaGV4L7iTZAQ_xBWmKU_xTZquGaYMzMm8javZHQZG4nVeVKAuhJSvkmm9v2A0YV1Dkq_4yNywEc73kYpzZFLkZxduca3WLsAg7SZCA46VZadR_6JqILT6QnkTVfUXi0O6Qe3-C653oNrErJKPihVmx1apU96qNboXlo4LzDA3ACuO763QM_qUUCpg
```